# How do I link to an open accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I found this [accordion](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbXOEO) suitable for what I'm doing. 
Now I'd like to force it open its panel when clicking on blabla.com/ab.html#open but I'm not familiar with JQ

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<h3>Accordion collapse with rotating icon</h3>
<div class="panel-group wrap" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      Collapsible item #1
    </a>
  </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of panel -->


</div>
<!-- end of #accordion -->
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.collapse.in').prev('.panel-heading').addClass('active');
$('#accordion, #bs-collapse')
.on('show.bs.collapse', function(a) {
  $(a.target).prev('.panel-heading').addClass('active');
})
.on('hide.bs.collapse', function(a) {
  $(a.target).prev('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
$(document).on('click','.click-me',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/me5w3h0r/3/)

**Updated**

Add this code to open panel according to url

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    var start = url.substr(url.indexOf("#"));
    $(start).collapse('show');
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NVt2V8rYlow1NkBQ5EVy?p=preview)

Add this code to change url on panel click

```
$("#accordion").on("show.bs.collapse",function(a){
    var curr=$(a.target).attr("id");
    var url = window.location.href;
    var start = window.location.hash;
    if(start.length>0){
        window.location.href = url.replace(start,"#"+curr);
    }
    else{
        window.location.href = url+"#"+curr;
    }
});
```

Comment: The link appears in the browser [link] (https://jimmydance.com/payments.html#workshops) however, it doesn't open the panel nor automatically neither manually.

Comment: Of course, I'm having "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" on G dev

Comment: Just want to ask,in your question its onClick the panel need to be open.But you share me the link,does you want to open panel when reaching this url?

Comment: Yes, please! I want everyone who has the link to be able to open the respective panel.

Comment: G dev says "Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function"
The panels are opening as expected but it doesn't respond when using the link

Comment: I'm using jQ 3.2.1 and BootStrap 3

Comment: Can you show me the code for accordion?where did you write all your js code?can you please share?

Comment: I see this error `(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and also i cann't see any panel openings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144081/discussion-between-amal-and-jim).

Comment: Hi there
I need your help [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224757/uncaught-error-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression)
I think the issue is related to the accordion

Comment: sure.when i am back to my pc,will check this

Comment: Hey Amal, did you have a look?

Comment: Hi Jim,Sorry for the delay.Will look now.

Comment: i am getting these errors `(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` `(index):3 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` in home page.Just to ask does everthing works fine on yours(accordion)

Comment: please see this https://jimmydance.com/payments.html/js/jjsa.js I found some html tag in this.please check this.if found remove that

Comment: Although the accordion works fine I think I need to escape some special characters. Mind that the issue occurs only when accessing the website domain, not the other pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145448/discussion-between-amal-and-jim).

Comment: Amal, I need your help, again!
In the same scenario, I want to link to a nested accordion (from an external link).
Can you edit the snippet, please?

Comment: sure Jim will do it

Comment: Let's assume there is a nested accordion inside the first one parent. All I want is, when calling the nested from the link, to open both the parent and the nested.

Comment: Yes,it can be done.sorry Jim,now i am busy with my work will do it shortly

Comment: JIm,when calling parent does the nested need to be open or just need to open both on nested call.And is nested calling from menu like others?

Comment: When calling parent only parent should open and children must be closed. When calling whatever children then parent and the specified child in the link should open.
"And is nested calling from menu like others?" I can't get what you mean.

Comment: Sorry,i mean r u calling nested child from your menu bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146845/discussion-between-jim-and-amal).