# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /

Tags: jquery

I'm receiving this error only in home page. How do I solve this?

 If I visit `example.com` but it works good when I visit `example.com/index.html`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var url =
        window.location.href;
    var start = url.substr(url.indexOf("#"));
    $(start).collapse('show');
    $('.collapse.in').prev('.panel-heading').addClass('active');
    $("#accordion, #bs-collapse").on("show.bs.collapse", function(a) {
        $(a.target).prev('.panel-heading').addClass('active');
        var curr =
            $(a.target).attr("id");
        var url = window.location.href;
        var start = window.location.hash;
        if (start.length > 0) {
            window.location.href = url.replace(start, "#" + curr);
        } else {
            window.location.href = url + "#" + curr;
        }
        $("#accordion, #bs-collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse',
            function(a) {
                $(a.target).prev('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Share the link, HTML, JS code to understand the problem better.

Comment: Here they are: https://jimmydance.com/js/jjsa.js & https://jimmydance.com

Comment: I think the links you gave will be helpful to help you know the problem.Sorry they won't be.Please show some manageable code which you think might be causing error.

Comment: I edited the question as I found that it occurs since I implemented a new accordion in one of the pages.
Sorry, I have no idea about jQ. However, the issue occurs when I'm loading X.com if I open X.com/index.html I'm not receiving this error.

Comment: @MilanChheda I edited the question to include the code.
I'm pretty sure that this triggers the issue.

Comment: @IshanMahajan I edited the question including the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below code**

you only need these code in your payments.html page.But it gets called every where,it cause the error

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".panel-group").length > 0) {
        var url = window.location.href;
        var start = url.substr(url.indexOf("#"));
        $(start).collapse('show');
        $('.collapse.in').prev('.panel-heading').addClass('active');
        $("#accordion, #bs-collapse").on("show.bs.collapse", function(a) {
            $(a.target).prev('.panel-heading').addClass('active');
            var curr =
                $(a.target).attr("id");
            var url = window.location.href;
            var start = window.location.hash;
            if (start.length > 0) {
                window.location.href = url.replace(start, "#" + curr);
            } else {
                window.location.href = url + "#" + curr;
            }
            $("#accordion, #bs-collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse',
                function(a) {
                    $(a.target).prev('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
                });
        });
    }
});
```